# Rails, CarrierWave, and S3: Moving old files from old model to new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a Legacy Model with files stored with CarrierWave and S3, and I need to move these files to a new model because of a redesign.

I have tried to do it this way:

```
NewModel.create(:name => "bla", :file => old_model_object.file)
```

But that leads to this error:

```
[WARNING] fog: the specified s3 bucket name(my-bucket-development) is not a
valid dns name, which will negatively impact performance. For details see:
    docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/… 
rake aborted! undefined method `content_length' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I move the old files to the new model?

Comment: What is not working properly? Any error messages?

Comment: [WARNING] fog: the specified s3 bucket name(my-bucket-development) is not a valid dns name, which will negatively impact performance.  For details see: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html
rake aborted!
undefined method `content_length' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @user2653660 perhaps you need to try with `remote_url` because s3 exposed a url for you also if the id of the model is going to remain same i advise not to do the moving of file just replace your `store_dir` to one currently in s3 and it would work after which believe you have to dump the uploader column of old model to new model table uploader column

Comment: There are plenty of other way to do this as well if there a relationship between ur new and old model perhaps then dont even have to do anything just `delegate` the method of the old model to new model